# How to determine and show the expiry time of a specific session

Tags: redis, spring-session

I am using `spring-session` and wondering how to know a specific session expired.

Querying Redis persistence, I find a couple of the following lines

```
[ root@redis-master-6fbbc44567-cc28m:/data ]$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "spring:session:expirations:1581796140000"
2) "spring:session:sessions:23d6aff1-cb43-44f6-920d-cc3536ab6d46"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Converting the expirations to date, they are equavalent to `Mon 14 Feb 52095 16:40:00 GMT` which looks weird at the year.
We might extract the expired time from `HttpSession`:

```
HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession()
long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
long expiryTime = currTime + httpSession.getMaxInactiveInterval()
```

But the snippet doesn't show exactly what weed anticipate.

I reckon we need to retrieve expirations from Redis server instead.

What am I doing wrong here?

Any of you know how to retrieve sessions and expirations from Redis?

Answer (score 2):

The expiration timestamp `1581796140000` is a Unix epoch in milliseconds and translates to GMT: Saturday, February 15, 2020 7:49:00 PM.

Comment: Thanks for replying. You're right. I used the wrong syntax to convert a Unix epoch to GMT. Do you have any idea of retrieving expirations from Redis?

Comment: Assuming you mean a Redis key expiration, you can get the Time to Live in seconds using [`TTL`](https://redis.io/commands/ttl), `PTTL` for milliseconds. If you want a Redis-server date, you need to call `TIME` besides TTL and do the math, but it will carry an error for the time between the two calls.